# Magento 2 : Store value in a variable via knockout loop in html

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I am new to KO, in my html file I am printing a value like this -

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: JSON.parse($parent.options), as: 'option' } -->
    <!-- ko if: option.label === 'AAA' || option.label === 'BBB'  -->
        <dd class="values" data-bind="html: option.value"></dd>
    <!-- /ko -->    
<!-- /ko -->
```

And its working fine . But what I want is, I want assign all values of loop to a variable and want to print after loop. Like we do in php-

```
foreach($data as $key=> $index){
    if($key==0)
        $var = $index['value'];
    else
        $var .= ' '.$index['value'];    
}

echo $var
```

Want to do the same in KO's html file using above KO loop.

Please help me in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use ifnot binding to accomplish this as follows ;

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: JSON.parse($parent.options), as: 'option' } -->
    <!-- ko if: option.label === 'AAA' || option.label === 'BBB'  -->
        <dd class="values" data-bind="html: option.value"></dd>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: option.label === 'AAA' || option.label === 'BBB'  -->
        <dd class="values" data-bind="html: ' ' + option.value"></dd>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```